# psql -U postgres not working & not installed using brew

Tags: django, postgresql, macos

Every time I try to run `psql -U postgres` in my terminal, I get this response.

```
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
```

I did **not** install this through **brew** instead though postgres.app

When I enter the command `postgres -V` I get the response `postgres -V postgres (PostgreSQL) 14.5`

Comment: The error indicates you have not started the Postgres server or it is started but not listening on port 5432. All `postgres -V` is telling you is that Postgres is installed and the vesrion.

Comment: does ps auxwww | grep postgres outputs something like `/Library/PostgreSQL/14.5/bin/postgres -D /Library/PostgreSQL/14.5/data` ? if so, can you try `/Library/PostgreSQL/14.5/bin/pg_ctl start -D /Library/PostgreSQL/14.5/data -l postgres.log` in order to start your postgresql database, then try to run psql -U postgres again ? the first command may output a different path, try adapting the 2nd and 3rd commands accordingly